# How to animate/move an element like on slaveryfootprint.org homepage

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

When scrolling down the home page of Slavery Footprint http://slaveryfootprint.org/ various elements move into view. These items are not animated once a certain threshold is passed but rather they move incrementally when the user scrolls - when you scroll back up, these items move in the opposite direction too. Does that make sense?

I use jQuery btw..

Cheers

Comment: The effect you are reffering to is usually called parallax scrolling, and a search for that term should give you some tutorials and plugins to look at.

Comment: I know all about parallax scrolling but I think this is different to that. Parallax scrolling is when elements move around the screen at different speeds (in relation to the scroll speed) to give the appearance of depth from the viewer. Do you see? All I need, is to move something as the page is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jquery scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)
Example
http://jsfiddle.net/gR25R/106/

There are several plugins out there to provide better control on mousewheel.

Comment: You suggest a solution, and then say there are better ones out there? How about sharing those too?

Comment: Plugin site of jquery is not available at the moment, so i can't link one:) http://plugins.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugins that allow you to do this, you'd have to code it yourself.

As Antoine Kociuba said, this is a great tutorial to help you get started: http://pehaa.com/2011/08/intriguing-animate-on-scroll-effect-jquery-tutorial/